# Redis - Check is a given set of ids are part of a redis list/hash

Tags: redis

I have a large set of ids (around 100000) which I want to store in redis.

I am looking for the most optimal way through which I can check if a given list of ids, what are the ids that are part of my set.

If I use a redis set, I can use SISMEMBER to check if a id is part of my set, but in this case I want to check if, given a list of ids, which one is part of my set.

Example:

```
redis> SADD myset "1"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD myset "2"
(integer) 2
redis> MYCOMMAND myset "[1,2,4,5]"
(list) 1, 2
```

Does anything of this sort exist already ?

thanks !

Comment: Look at `SINTER`

Comment: But isn’t that between 2 keys ? Can I use a user input as one of the keys instead ?

Comment: Nope, you'll have to create a key with the user's input for that. Alternatively, provide the user's input to a Lua script which will iterate over it, invoke Redis' SISMEMBER and return the results.